# Use RefTeX to manage a global bib database

Tags: auctex, reftex-mode

I would like to have the following workflow. First, I create a global bib file, which contains all bibliography entries that I may use across all projects. Then, for each project, I can create an empty bib file for that project (or use `reftex-create-bibtex-file`). Whenever I call `reftex-citation`, that entry in the global bib file was copied to the project specific bib file.

Is this possible in Emacs?

Comment: The right answer to this one would be: Clearly, it is possible. (You note the sarkasm. It sounds like a specification for an engineering task.) Have a look at [ebib](https://joostkremers.github.io/ebib/). One of its ''LaTeX integration'' capabilities is: "Creating a .bib file from a .bbl file, allowing you to create a .bib file for a LaTeX document containing only the references in the document. (Currently only works for .bbl files generated by BibTeX.)"

Comment: @Tobias Thanks. Actually this can also be done by using `reftex-create-bib-file`. The question, however, is how to set a global bib file such that reftex or ebib can extract references from that file.

Comment: You could first use the global bibfile for `\bibliography`, let `latex` and `bibtex` do their jobs. At the end you let `ebib` create the local bibliography file from the `bbl` file.

Comment: @Tobias Thanks for pointing it out. This was the way I did before, until now I have to colaborate with other people on editing the source files, which makes this approach unfeasible anymore, as far as I can tell. Do you have any better ideas for this situation?

Comment: You should have added `reftex-create-bibtex-file` to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can locally override the behavior of `reftex-get-bibfile-list` to return the global bibliographies.

```el
(defcustom reftex-global-bibfile-list '()
  "List of global bibliographies for `reftex-mode'"
  :group 'reftex-citation-support
  :type '(repeat string))

(defun reftex-global-bibfile-list ()
  "Just returns `reftex-global-bibfile-list'.
Can be used as local advice of `reftex-get-bibfile-list'"
  reftex-global-bibfile-list)

(defun reftex-create-bibtex-file-from-global (bibfile)
  "See `reftex-create-bibtex-file'.
The only modification is that not the bibfile list of the LaTeX file is used but
reftex-global-bibfile-list."
  (interactive "FNew BibTeX file:")
  (unwind-protect
      (progn
        (advice-add #'reftex-get-bibfile-list :override #'reftex-global-bibfile-list)
        (reftex-create-bibtex-file bibfile))
    (advice-remove #'reftex-get-bibfile-list #'reftex-global-bibfile-list)))
```

Comment: Thanks! It would be nice to see this integrated in reftex.

Comment: @xuhdev A regular implementation would look very different. Furthermore, there are many variations of the theme. For an instance: Instead of replacing the action of `reftex-get-bibfile-list` one could always add an extra-list of bibliographies in `reftex-get-bibfile-list` from some emacs-variable.